# Load data in UIpickerview from database

Tags: ios, sqlite, uipickerview

Am new to iphone development.
Now,i want to know about how to load data in UIpickerview from database.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of database? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Fetch the data from database for a particular field for eg. country make a NSArray form that data and load that NSArray to UIPickerView.Use that array in UIPickerView Delegate and Datasource methods.

Answer (score 0):

first import the UIPickerDelegate and UIPickerDatasource to your ViewController where you implement the picker

[image]

Now, in the viewDidLoad... add the following

```
self.picker.delegate=self;
self.picker.dataSource=self;
```

and now here is an example of implementing those delegate methods

here i have an array of years to be implemented in picker...to pick an year just copy the below code and replace the bodies  according to your need..

```
//Picker DataSource 



       - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView
         {


            return 1;
        }

        - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
        {
            return [_yearArray count];
        }

        - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
        {
            return [_yearArray objectAtIndex:row];
        }

        // Picker Delegate
        - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
        {


        }
```

Comment: Well,read from question properly,i have a database and i need to display the data in uipickerview from database.Any idea?